# What can I do after submitting the wrong app to the App Store?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I submitted the wrong app. Is there any procedure to resubmit another app?

Comment: not only did you submit the wrong app, but you submitted your question to the wrong place as well!

Comment: "software tools commonly used by programmers" would seem to apply

Answer (score 4):

In iTunes Connect, you can manually reject the binary you submitted. This will stop it at whatever step in the approval process it is. Then you can modify whatever you need to and resubmit the app.

If you need to create a totally different app in iTunes Connect, go ahead and reject the binary on that app you already submitted and delete that app. Then create the new one as you did the first time.